# Python formatting DataFrame table colours and borders

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to format my python DataFrame table's colours and borders. I am especially having difficulty formatting the top left corner colour, and borders around an entire row rather than individual cells.

**Here is the code for the table I have now:**

```
# create a table summary
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("Type", ''), ("alpha", "x"), 
                           ("alpha", "y"),
                           ("alpha","z"),
                            ("beta", '')])

data = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        [1, 2, 3, 4], 
        [5, 6, 7, 8], 
        [9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]]

table = pd.DataFrame(data = data, 
                      index = index,
                      columns =  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['data'], ['', '  ', '   ', '    ']]))


# set styles
styles=[{'selector':'th','props': [
        ('vertical-align','center'),
        ('text-align', 'center'), 
        ('font-size', '12px')]}, 
        
        {'selector': 'caption','props': [
        ('color', 'black'),
        ('font-size', '10px'), 
        ('font-weight', 'bold'),
        ('caption-side', 'bottom')]}, 
       
        {'selector': 'th:not(.index_name)', 'props': [
        ('background-color', 'lightblue'), 
        ('color', 'white')]}, 
       
        {'selector': 'th.col_heading.level0', 'props': [
        ('font-size', '15px'), 
        ('background-color', 'darkblue'),
        ("border", "1px solid darkblue")]},

        {'selector': 'th.col_heading.level1', 'props': [
        ('background-color', 'darkblue'),
        ("border", "1px solid darkblue")]},
        
        {'selector': 'td:hover', 'props': [
        ('background-color', '#ffffb3')]}, 
       
        {"selector": "th", "props": [
        ("border", "1px solid lightblue")]},
       
        {"selector" :".row0", "props": [
        ("border","2px solid darkblue"),
        ('background-color', 'lightblue'), 
        ('color', 'white'),
        ('font-weight', 'bold')]}]


table = table.style.set_caption("Some Caption").set_table_styles(styles)

table
```

**The table the code produces:**

[image: code table]

**The table I would like to produce:**

[image: table I would like]

**EDIT: code and result using answer below:**

```
# create a table summary
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("Type", ''), ("alpha", "x"), 
                           ("alpha", "y"),
                           ("alpha","z"),
                            ("beta", '')])

data = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        [1, 2, 3, 4], 
        [5, 6, 7, 8], 
        [9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]]

table = pd.DataFrame(data = data, 
                      index = index,
                      columns =  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['data'], ['', ' ', '  ', '   ']]))

# set styles
header = {'selector': 'th', 'props': 
          [('background-color', '#00008b'), ('color', 'white'), ('text-align', 'center'), ('vertical-align', 'centre'), ('font-weight', 'bold')]}

header_level0 = {'selector': 'th.col_heading.level0', 'props': [('font-size', '15px')]}

index = {'selector': 'th.row_heading', 'props': 
         [('background-color', '#5b9bd5'), ('color', 'white'), ('text-align', 'center'), ('font-weight', 'bold')]}

top_row = {'selector': 'td.data.row0', 'props': 
         [('background-color', '#5b9bd5'), ('color', 'white'), ('text-align', 'center'), ('font-weight', 'bold')]}

borders_bottom1 = {'selector': '.row0', 'props': 
                  [('border-bottom', '1px solid #00008b'), ('border-top', '1px solid #00008b')]}

borders_bottom2 = {'selector': '.row_heading.level0.row1', 'props': 
                  [('border-bottom', '1px solid #00008b')]}

borders_bottom3 = {'selector': '.row3', 'props': 
                  [('border-bottom', '1px solid #00008b')]}

borders_bottom4 = {'selector': '.row1', 'props': 
                  [('border-bottom', '1px dashed #00008b')]}

borders_bottom5 = {'selector': '.row2', 'props': 
                  [('border-bottom', '1px dashed #00008b')]}

borders_right = {'selector': '.row_heading.level1', 'props': 
                 [('border-right', '1px solid #00008b')]}

# apply styles
table = table.style.set_table_styles([header, header_level0, index, top_row, borders_bottom1, borders_bottom2, borders_bottom3, borders_bottom4, borders_bottom5, borders_right])

table
```

[image: table using answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a table summary
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("Type", ""), 
                                   ("Alpha", "x"), 
                                   ("Alpha", "y"),
                                   ("Alpha", "z"),
                                   ("Beta", "")])

data = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], 
        [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], 
        [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

table = pd.DataFrame(data = data, 
                     index = index,
                     columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["data"], ["","","",""]]))

# set styles
header = {'selector': 'thead, th', 
          'props': 'background-color: #00008b; color: white; text-align: center;'}

index_col = {'selector': 'th.row_heading',
         'props': 'background-color: #5b9bd5; color: white; text-align: center;'}

types_row = {'selector': 'td.data.row0',
         'props': 'background-color: #5b9bd5; color: white; text-align: center;'}

borders_horizontal = {'selector': '.row0, .row_heading.level0.row1, .row3',
         'props': 'border-bottom: 2px solid #000066'}

borders_vertical = {'selector': '.row_heading.level1',
         'props': 'border-right: 2px solid #000066'}

hide_row = {'selector': 'thead tr:nth-child(2)', 'props': [('display', 'none')]}

# apply stiles
style = table.style.set_table_styles([header, index_col, types_row, 
                                      borders_horizontal, borders_vertical, 
                                      hide_row])

style
```

Returns

[image]

Also you may find helpful to use `print(table.style.render())` or `print(style.to_html())` to get html tags and css styles those has been applied to pandas dataframe.

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful. I used your answer and adjusted it slightly (as shown in my question edit). Do you know why the 'selector': '.row3' bottom-border is printing as 2px even though I have specified 1px? Also, do you know if it possible to merge cells (e.g the cells around 'data'). And lastly, how did you get the exact # colours that you used? Thank you!

Comment: I use `Eyedropper` tool to pick up color name from browser window elements. `Eyedropper` tool is build-in add-on in Mozilla Firefox. Also some alternatives can be found in browser [add-ons and themes](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=eyedropper).

Comment: Thanks! and do you have any idea why some of the borders sometimes show up as thicker even though they are all 1px?

Comment: I don't know what is the issue with border rendering in your environment. I ran your version of the code and all the borders are the same 1px thick.